# How do I load this chart javascript async? (Tradingview chart api)

Tags: javascript, iframe, pagespeed, tradingview-api

My page speed is being damaged by the TradingView chart widget. I need to load the javascript async / defer. However, adding that to the script makes it disappear.

I use it for charts on this swedish page: https://cryptorunner.com/sv/hur-man-koper-bitcoin/

With this specific code in the wordpress editor:

```html
<div class="tradingview-widget-container"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "autosize": true,
  "symbol": "BITFINEX:BTCUSD",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "Light",
  "style": "3",
  "locale": "sv_SE",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "hide_top_toolbar": true,
  "hide_legend": true,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_7589b"
}
  );
  </script></div>
```

You will find the code here:

https://uk.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/

I would really appreciate if someone could help me lazy load this chart. Any ideas why it doesn't​ work?

Comment: It loads fast in my browser on the link you provided, maybe its your internet?

Comment: Yes the page works. But I need to async load the chart or remove it. Google PageSpeed Insights drops 10 points with this widget. Do you know how I could load this async? Adding async / defer to the script don't work...

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading their script async and initate the chart once the whole page is fully loaded.

Vanilla/native JS minimal example from https://flippening.org/:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_d2337"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/ETHBTC/?exchange=BINANCE" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">ETHBTC Rates</span></a> by TradingView</div>
</div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        new TradingView.MediumWidget(
        {
        "symbols": [
          [
            "BINANCE:ETHBTC|12M"
          ]
        ],
        "chartOnly": true,
        "width": 1000,
        "height": 400,
        "locale": "en",
        "colorTheme": "light",
        "gridLineColor": "rgba(240, 243, 250, 0)",
        "trendLineColor": "#2962FF",
        "fontColor": "#787B86",
        "underLineColor": "rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.3)",
        "underLineBottomColor": "rgba(41, 98, 255, 0)",
        "isTransparent": false,
        "autosize": false,
        "showFloatingTooltip": false,
        "container_id": "tradingview_d2337"
      }
        );
    };
</script>
</html>
```

But at some point, if you really want to optimize performance you cannot rely on a solution like tradingview. They provide a free solution to millions of websites and load a bunch load of 3rd party code which will slow down your page.

Either compare different options or do it yourself (minimal charts js library + your own data)